# Tackling Session Expired and Authentication Failed in pop up window

Tags: java, javascript, web-applications, popup, session-timeout

When the session expires in the application or the authentication is denied for click of some button, we display a message ('session expired' or 'authentication failed') and then take the user to the login page.

The problem is, when the session expires on some screen, and the user clicks on a popup link after the session has expired, the pop up window opens, and then the login page is displayed in the popup window. Same case for authentication failed.

What I need is , on click of the hyper link, it should directly go to the login page(I understand that hyper link is not hitting the server)

How can we get around the situation.

We are using a Java based web app

This is the code we use for opening the popup

```
    window.open(url,"_blank","directories=no, 
    resize=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=720, height=380,
    top=250,left=250");
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a scriplet to control it.

```
// assuming that you have some kind of variable in the session which will get null if your session gets expired 
    <% if(session.getAttribute("uid")!=null){%> 
        window.open(url,"_blank","directories=no, 
        resize=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=720, height=380,
        top=250,left=250");
    <%}else{%>
        //wirte your redirect js
    <%}%>
```

Comment: I will suggest to use JSTL instead.

Comment: @user2434 Instead of `if(...)... else...` use `<c:choose> <c:when> <c:otherwise>` or `<c:if>`

Comment: @user2434 this might help http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?347426-JSTL-and-sessions-need-tip.